# How to group a python data frame by multilevel rows?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following multi-level data frame:

```
Year   2016                    2017                 
Quarter  3   4                 1                 2      
Month  Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec   Jan  Feb    Mar   Apr   May   Jun
A      0.16  0.95  0.92  0.45  0.30  0.35  0.95  0.88  0.18  0.10
B      0.88  0.67  0.07  0.70  0.74  0.33  0.77  0.21  0.81  0.85
C      0.79  0.56  0.13  0.19  0.94  0.23  0.72  0.62  0.66  0.93
```

I want to sum up over the quarters, so that the final result is as follows:

```
Year     2016        2017   
Quarter  3     4     1     2
A        0.16  2.32  1.60  1.16
B        0.88  1.44  1.85  1.86
C        0.79  0.89  1.89  2.21
```

I tried with the following formula:

```
df= df.groupby('Quarter').transform('sum')
```

but  I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'Quarter'
```

Clearly that's the wrong way to approach it. Could anyone please a solution or to approach finding one.

**Additional information**

The output of the `df.index` command is: `Index([u'A', u'B',u'C'],dtype='object', name=u'DF name')`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide code to generate your dataframe, as @Matt Messersmith mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just using `sum`

```
df.sum(level=[0,1],axis=1)
Out[14]: 
year    2016        2017      
quater     3     4     1     2
A       0.16  2.32  1.60  1.16
B       0.88  1.44  1.84  1.87
C       0.79  0.88  1.89  2.21
```

Comment: That's the error I receive `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: @Newskooler `df.sum(level=['Year','Quater'],axis=1)
`

Comment: It worked. The reason it did not work the first time is because I had `df=df.replace(0, '')`. Clearly a mistake on my side. Thanks!

Comment: @Newskooler Ha ,Would you like consider accept it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use groupby in pandas you group data based on columns data. But you have your groups in rows.  All you need is to transpose your df before grouping and after.

Here is code you need:

First let's create df like yours:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(2016, 3, 'Sep', 'A'),
                                   (2016, 3, 'Sep', 'B'),
                                   (2016, 3, 'Sep', 'C'),
                                   (2016, 4, 'Oct', 'A'),
                                   (2016, 4, 'Oct', 'B'),
                                   (2016, 4, 'Oct', 'C'),
                                   (2016, 4, 'Nov', 'A'),
                                   (2016, 4, 'Nov', 'B'),
                                   (2016, 4, 'Nov', 'C'),
                                   (2017, 1, 'Jan', 'A'),
                                   (2017, 1, 'Jan', 'B'),
                                   (2017, 1, 'Jan', 'C'),
                                   (2017, 1, 'Feb', 'A'),
                                   (2017, 1, 'Feb', 'B'),
                                   (2017, 1, 'Feb', 'C'),
                                   ], names=['Year', 'Quarter', 'Month', 'Group'])

raw_df = pd.Series(range(15), index=index)

df = raw_df.unstack([0,1,2])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Year    2016         2017    
Quarter    3   4        1    
Month    Sep Oct Nov  Jan Feb
Group                        
A          0   3   6    9  12
B          1   4   7   10  13
C          2   5   8   11  14
```

Looks exactly like in your example. Now you need only 1 line of code:

```
new_df = df.transpose().groupby(['Year', 'Quarter']).sum().transpose()
print(new_df)
```

Here's your output:

```
Year    2016     2017
Quarter    3   4    1
Group                
A          0   9   21
B          1  11   23
C          2  13   25
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`df.sum(level=['Year', 'Quater'], axis=1)`

**EDIT**: thanks [Matt Messersmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3691783/matt-messersmith) for note on transpose

**Reproducing full example**:

```
import pandas as pd

tuples = [(2016, 3, 'Sep'), (2016, 4, 'Oct'), (2016, 4, 'Nov'),
          (2016, 4, 'Dec'), (2017, 1, 'Jan'), (2017, 1, 'Feb'),
          (2017, 1, 'Mar'), (2017, 2, 'Apr'), (2017, 2, 'May'),
          (2017, 2, 'Jun')]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Year', 'Quater', 'Month'])

df = pd.DataFrame([(0.16, 0.88, 0.79), (0.95, 0.67, 0.56), (0.92, 0.07, 0.13), 
                   (0.45, 0.70, 0.19), (0.30, 0.74, 0.94), (0.35, 0.33, 0.23), 
                   (0.95, 0.77, 0.72), (0.88, 0.21, 0.62), (0.18, 0.81, 0.66), 
                   (0.10, 0.85, 0.93)], 
                  index=index, 
                  columns=["A", "B", "C"])
df = df.T
print(df.sum(level=['Year', 'Quater'], axis=1))
```

Comment: I tried this too, but I get the following error `ValueError: level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex`

Comment: @Newskooler can you please provide the result of this line `print(df.index)?`

Comment: This is the result `Index([u'A', u'B', u'C'], dtype='object', name=u'DF name')`

Comment: Can you supply code to generate the dataframe, and move that `print(df.index)` output into the question so others can see it without having to scroll through commends

Comment: I think you need to transpose the dataframe you created, and then do the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try transpose the data then `sum` it by the index you want and transpose it back the way you want

```
df.transpose().sum(level=[0,1]).transpose()
```

In case you needed to pivot your results.