# ValueError when using multi-level sum on Pandas DataFrame with empty columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

**Largely updated question**: I found the issue causing the error: The dataframe contains a few empty columns. Added a reproducible example.

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this but is much larger (2500x288):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((['A','A','A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                                                     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
                                                     ['i', 'ii', 'i', 'ii', 'i', 'ii', 'i', 'ii'])))


          A                                       B                              
          a         b         c         d         a         b         c         d
          i        ii         i        ii         i        ii         i        ii
0 -0.344673  0.711897 -1.306805 -1.926644 -0.351334 -0.864423 -1.023401 -0.284710
1  0.730107  0.245481 -0.570591  1.740258  0.779193 -0.151460  2.082086 -0.008099
2 -0.806092 -1.364315  0.845041  1.739843  0.737802 -2.232088  0.114731 -1.028346
```

Now I would like to sum it across two levels of the MultiIndex columns, such as:

```
df.sum(level=[1,2], axis=1)

          a         b         c         d
          i        ii         i        ii
0 -0.696007 -0.152525 -2.330206 -2.211354
1  1.509300  0.094021  1.511495  1.732159
2 -0.068290 -3.596403  0.959772  0.711497
```

However, as soon as columns are empty, a `ValueError` occurs.

```
df.loc[:, ('A','b','ii')] = None
df.sum(level=[1,2], axis=1)

ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
```

Single-level sums work (e.g. `df.sum(level=1, axis=1)`). Also, [using `transpose()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51674013/2075003), such as `df.transpose().sum(level=[1,2], axis=0).transpose()` works, although it is incredibly slow. This tells me that this may be more of a bug and not me "doing it wrong".

Using `df.groupby(level=[1,2], axis=1).sum()` gives the same error.

Comment: @ALollz Yes, because transposing twice works with the very same df

Comment: Hi, what version of `pandas` do you use and what is dimensionality of df, with which you starting to have this problem

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin The DF has 2500 rows x 288 columns. Pandas is 0.23.4 on Python 3.7.2. I hope I find a bit more time today to play with the df and see when the issue starts appearing. So far I am totally clueless.

Comment: Generated df with 100000 rows x 676 columns with that: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000, len(string.ascii_lowercase) * len(string.ascii_uppercase)), columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((list(itertools.chain(*[[l] * len(string.ascii_lowercase) for l in string.ascii_uppercase])), [l for i in range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)) for l in string.ascii_lowercase], ['i' if ord(l) % 2 == 1 else 'ii' for i in range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)) for l in string.ascii_lowercase])))`. Sum still works. Seems like problem is not the size.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I added the full stack which may help finding the issue. Thank you for your help so far! If I find more, I will update the question.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin I found the issue! It is the fact that the df has empty columns.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24671

Answer (score 0):

One could use `.fillna()`. However, this is more of a workaround and I would prefer to preserve `None` values... *Better solutions welcome!*

```
df.fill(0).sum(level=[1,2], axis=1)
```

This is a bug in pandas 0.23.4: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24671